# Ragged/Jagged Array Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, arrays, null, ragged

in the code that follows I take `counter[]` which has a lot of values within it that are 0, and determine the amount of 0 values.

With that I create the first half of a jagged array (counter3) that has a row for every line in `counter[]` with a value, and columns equal to the value within `counter[]`.

Initializing with `counter3[i] = new double[counter[i]` did not succeed, so i created the class MakeJagArray, which takes a value and returns a double array of 0 values the size of the number given.

Setting the value of `counter3[i][j]` is a null pointer. Not sure why

```
    int counter2 = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<counter.length; i++){
        if (counter[i]>0){
            counter2++;
        }
    }

    double[][]counter3 =new double[counter2][];

    int i = 0;
    for(j=0;j<counter.length;j++){
        if(counter[j]>0){
            //MakeJagArray pHT = new MakeJagArray(counter[j]);
            counter3[i] = new double[counter[j]];
            //counter3[i] = pHT.go();
            i++;
        }
    }
    double q;
    for(i=0;i<counter3.length; i++){
        for(j=0; j<counter3.length; j++){
        counter3[i][j] = 0.0; //q=linespositions[i][j];
        }
    }


public class MakeJagArray {
    int num;
    public MakeJagArray(int num){
        this.num= num;
    }

    public double[] go(){
        double[]poop = new double[num];
        for(int i = 0; i<poop.length;i++){
            poop[i] = 0.0;
        }
        return poop;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(j=0; j<counter3.length; j++)` should probably be `for(j=0; j<counter3[i].length; j++)`

Comment: Check and see whether `counter3[i]` gets initialized.

Comment: @ajb that's an error but it would result in an IndexOutOfBoundsException instead of a NPE.

Comment: A couple of tips: 1) Try using more meaningful names, this will make understanding your code easier. 2) Debug your code to see what is null and then why. 3) If you can use lists instead.

Comment: struggling with debugger, but id bet that ajb is right, good catch. and most of these are really just placeholders, trying to get info into the right format, so thats why the names kinda blow

Comment: and that did in fact fix it, thanks! looks like i was just dumb, it was an index out of bounds, idk why i read null pointer